# How to display or embed an <iframe> in vb.net form

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to accomplish this output

[image]

but the result is this

[image]

is there any problem with this code?

```
Dim html As String = "<html><head>"
html &= "<iframe width='1000' height='300' frameborder='0' scrolling='no' marginheight='0' marginwidth='0' src= 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='" & MainForm.latLng.Text & "'&h1=en&z=19&amp;output=embed'></iframe>"
html &= "</body></html>"
Me.WebBrowser1.DocumentText = String.Format(html)
```

or is there any other way to achieve my desired output jus like the picture above?

Comment: You could try changing your first line to Dim html As String = "<html><head></head><body>"  although from the error it looks like Google is restricting it's content from being displayed in this way

Comment: Does the example in the [The Maps Embed API overview](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-started) work for you?

Comment: @AndrewMorton yep this works for me thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You didn't add the URL in the code. No wonder why it didn't work!

Comment: Yes there is `src= 'https://maps.google.com/maps?q='" & MainForm.latLng.Text & "'&h1=en&z=19&amp;output=embed'` You need to scroll the code box!